# What is the best way to put more than 5 @Pathvariable in RestApi Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have too many @PathVariable in one endpoint. How I can minimize it, because it looks endless, maybe create one more objet with all this variable which I need and use @RequestBody or any other ways?

```
 @GetMapping("/city/{cityname}/{priceLess}/{priceGreater}/{untilityLess}/{untilityGreater}/{rentORbuy}/{furnished}/{renovated}/{roomsLess}/{roomsGreater}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Flat>> findCity(@PathVariable("cityname") String cityname,
                                               @PathVariable("priceLess") BigDecimal priceLess,
                                               @PathVariable("priceGreater") BigDecimal priceGreater,
                                               @PathVariable("untilityLess") BigDecimal untilityLess,
                                               @PathVariable("untilityGreater") BigDecimal untilityGreater,
                                               @PathVariable("rentORbuy") Boolean rentORbuy,
                                               @PathVariable("furnished") Boolean furnished,
                                               @PathVariable("renovated") Boolean renovated,
                                               @PathVariable("roomsLess") int roomsLess,
                                               @PathVariable("roomsGreater") int roomsGreater){}
```

Comment: That looks like an unusable API. If it's meant to be REST then filters should _not_ be part of the path. Put those into the query string or a post body instead (and when trying to read them be aware that most of them will probably be optional and thus don't have to be present).

Comment: @Thomas , but how I should get data from front part?

Comment: What front part? I assume the path `/city/{cityname}` is what identifies a city and everything else looks like optional filters and thus should be query parameters. The path would thus just be `/city/{cityname}` or, if `cityname` would be optional as well, maybe even just something like `/search`.

Comment: @Thomas, I don't really understand, front part I mean if user decides to filter flats with all variables I wrote, how backend will get it? through endpoint I thought and for that I wrote this long api or I am doing wrong? Because I am new in spring and restAPI.

Comment: If you're new you should have a deeper look into URLs and REST first, then look at how to map that in Spring. I already mentioned the keyword to look for: query path. The url being called might look like this with filters in the query path: `.../city/London?priceLess=1000&roomsGreater=3&rentOrBuy=rent`

Comment: You _could_ use @RequestParam to get the query or post body params but that might make the method signature very bloated. Alternatively you could try to get a handle to the request itself (I'm not sure how to do that in Spring) and extract the parameters from there or use a json object that you could pass and extract the parameters from (e.g. `{"priceLess":1000,"roomsGreater":3,"rentOrBuy":"rent"}` which might be parsed to a class named `Filters` or so).

Comment: @Thomas Thank you, I will check more detailed and try.

Comment: If you're looking to get a better understanding of queries, [Hyperskill](https://hyperskill.org/) has a project called "Web Quiz Engine" that you can do. It takes some time, but the path will teach you a lot about building an API, especially about POST Requests, wihich would be very helpful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same @GetMapping, and in method parameters instead of retrieving each value separately retrieve a Map<String, String>.

This map will contain all the path variables sent in the request and the values can be accessed using the variable name used in URI.

```
@GetMapping("/city/{cityname}/{priceLess}/{priceGreater}/{untilityLess}/{untilityGreater}/{rentORbuy}/{furnished}/{renovated}/{roomsLess}/{roomsGreater}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Flat>> findCity(@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVariables){}
```